# Parsing XML with attributes

Tags: java, xml-parsing

I want to parse this XML with Attribute and value. Now I am able to parse values but I am not able parse Attributes.

My XML:

```
   <Book>          
    <vendor>  
      <vendorPartyReference href="VENDOR"/>  
      <vendorDefinedValue fieldName="Bookuser">dav</vendorDefinedValue>  
      <vendorDefinedValue fieldName="ComUser">dav</vendorDefinedValue>  
      <vendorDefinedValue fieldName="Rate">1.02505</vendorDefinedValue>  
      <vendorDefinedValue fieldName="Points">0.00000</vendorDefinedValue>  
      <vendorDefinedValue fieldName="Design">DSF</vendorDefinedValue>  
      <vendorDefinedValue fieldName="Role">APPROVER</vendorDefinedValue>  
      <vendorDefinedValue fieldName="cover">DXBook12</vendorDefinedValue>  
      <vendorDefinedValue fieldName="Organization">Mannar</vendorDefinedValue>  
    </vendor>
    </Book>
```

I want to parse like fieldname as key and value as dav(values).

```
NodeList nList = document.getElementsByTagName("Book");         
        for(int s=0; s<nList.getLength() ; s++)
        {
            NodeList tsfpmlVendor = document.getElementsByTagName("vendor");             
             for(int i=0; i<tsfpmlVendor.getLength(); i++)
             {
                 Node tsfpmlVendorNode = tsfpmlVendor.item(i);
                Element tsfpmlVendorElement = (Element)tsfpmlVendorNode;                    
                for(int j=0; j<tsfpmlVendorElement.getElementsByTagName("vendorDefinedValue").getLength(); j++)
                {
                    listVendorField.add(tsfpmlVendorElement.getElementsByTagName("vendorDefinedValue").item(j).getTextContent());
                    System.out.println("kkk:  "+ tsfpmlVendorElement.getElementsByTagName("vendorDefinedValue").item(j).getAttributes().getLength());
                    System.out.println("kkk:  "+ tsfpmlVendorElement.getElementsByTagName("vendorDefinedValue").item(j).getNodeType());
                } 

             }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You question is not very clear. See http://www.w3.org/2003/01/dom2-javadoc/org/w3c/dom/Element.html for the Javadoc for W3C DOM  which will give  Attributes and their values.. I think you need

```
java.lang.String    getAttribute(java.lang.String name)
          // Retrieves an attribute value by name.
```

or

```
 Attr   getAttributeNode(java.lang.String name)
          //Retrieves an attribute node by name.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your code modified so it prints out the attribute like "filedName" and it's attribute-value like "Bookuser":

```
    NodeList nList = document.getElementsByTagName("Book");
    for (int s = 0; s < nList.getLength(); s++) {
        NodeList tsfpmlVendor = document.getElementsByTagName("vendor");
        for (int i = 0; i < tsfpmlVendor.getLength(); i++) {
            Node tsfpmlVendorNode = tsfpmlVendor.item(i);
            Element tsfpmlVendorElement = (Element) tsfpmlVendorNode;
            for (int j = 0; j < tsfpmlVendorElement.getElementsByTagName("vendorDefinedValue").getLength(); j++) {
                Node n = tsfpmlVendorElement.getElementsByTagName("vendorDefinedValue").item(j);
                listVendorField.add(n.getTextContent());
                NamedNodeMap nnm = n.getAttributes();
                for(int k=0; k<nnm.getLength(); k++) {
                    Node nattr = nnm.item(k);
                    System.out.println("Attribute "+nattr.getNodeName() + " => " + nattr.getNodeValue());
                }
                System.out.println("Value "+n.getTextContent());
                System.out.println("kkk:  " + tsfpmlVendorElement.getElementsByTagName("vendorDefinedValue").item(j).getAttributes().getLength());
                System.out.println("kkk:  " + tsfpmlVendorElement.getElementsByTagName("vendorDefinedValue").item(j).getNodeType());
            }

        }
    }
```